# File encryption with Raspberry Pi 4

Tags: encryption, raspberry-pi

If I have an Raspberry Pi 4, can I make something like this:

-to one USB port I connect pendrive

-the second USB port I connect with PC (with Windows10 system)

-when I move file from PC to pendrive, the file will be encrypted "inside" Raspberry(I want to create my own algorithm to this on Raspberry Pi)

-only way to decrypt file it will be connect pendrive to USB port in Raspberry and move back to PC.

Is this possible?

Comment: https://blog.gbaman.info/?p=699,  https://magpi.raspberrypi.org/articles/pi-zero-w-smart-usb-flash-drive

Comment: Sure can be done, although [you need a bridging cable](https://www.wikihow.com/Connect-Two-Computers-Using-USB) . Now what?

Comment: @MaartenBodewes So thats resolve problem with connection. But how to catch files in their way to pendrive?

Comment: Use a socket and a server, then write to disk? Obviously you don't want to write to mount the disk from a distance. WebDAV is a method that is used to write files to a web server, maybe that's something to consider. That way you can mount given the right software.

Comment: Looking at prices, you are probably better off getting two USB2 <-> 100 MBit LAN cables, by the way. These cost < 10 euro each if you look around a bit. USB3 <-> GBit is under 20 euro and you can combine the two as well.